# Store JSON in a variable in a REACT Helper component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch

I'm new in react and i'm trying to do a fetch and then store the data in a variable.

I don't understand why my `SetMovieResponse` is not working, I tried to stringify the JSON I'm sending but each time I look at my console the var is undefined.
The  `response` is fully clear but when I assign and display the data, it's undefined

Here is my code :

```
import React, { setState } from 'react';

const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
const PERSON_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_PERSON;
const MOVIE_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_MOVIE;

class Helper extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      answer: "",
      actorAnswer: [],
      movieAnswer: {},
      myInit: {method: "GET", mode: "cors"}
    }
  }

  setActorResponse = (response) => {
    this.setState({ actorAnswer: response});
  }

  setMovieResponse = (response) => {
    console.log("get call ? ",response)
    this.setState({ movieAnswer: JSON.stringify(response)});
    console.log("get SET ? ",this.movieAnswer)
  }

  fetchPersonFunction = (randomActor) => {
    fetch(`${PERSON_KEY}${randomActor}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, this.myInit)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
      })
      .then(response => {this.setActorResponse(response.total)})
    return (this.actorAnswer)
  }

    fetchMovieFunction = (randomMovie) => {
      fetch(`${MOVIE_KEY}${randomMovie}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, this.myInit)
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(response => {this.setMovieResponse(response)
        console.log("good response = ", response)
      })
      console.log("END res = ", this.movieAnswer);
      return (this.movieAnswer)
    }
}
export default Helper
```

So the `console.log("get call ? ",response)` Always display the JSON but the `console.log("get SET ? ",this.movieAnswer)`

I'm trying to call those function in a Game.js file like that :

`const Help = new Helper();`
 `console.log("MOVIE res = ",Help.fetchMovieFunction(randomMovie));`

Who is just under and suppose to set `movieAnswer` is always undefined.
Is there any reason why my `movieAnswer`  stay undefined when using setState ?

Thank's for you're help

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the state wrong. Your component state is accessible inside `this.state` property. ie, The value `movieAnswer` is available inside the `this.state` property.

Simply change all your state items to below,

```js
console.log("get SET ? ",this.state.movieAnswer)
```

also change `this.actorAnswer` to,

```js
this.state.actorAnswer
```

Also I don't think you need those return statements at the end of `fetchPersonFunction` and `fetchMovieFunction` functions.

Comment: Thank's for you're return, now I can see that my movieAnswer is an object, but it's still empty with no data in it like i never set it, is that normal ?
And I return those statement because i'm using those data in an other component.

Comment: Where are you printing your state? remeber `setState` is asynchronous and you will not see the updated state if you try to print your new state just after the `setState` call.

Comment: I'm trying to print it in another component called `Game` where I use my `Helper` class.

Comment: How are you trying to do it now? maybe some code would help

Comment: ``  const Help = new Helper();
    console.log("MOVIE res = ",Help.fetchMovieFunction(randomMovie));``

I init `Helper` and call the `function who are in the class

Just had the code at the end of the question

Comment: In that case, You don't even have to keep a state variable, you could've just returned the response from your api call function.

Comment: When i'm trying to just return the fetch I get this response in the console ` MOVIE res =  Promise {<pending>} `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236817/discussion-between-quentin-riols-and-nithinpp).